# Bind loading signed zone with outdated serial

Tags: bind, dnssec, keys

I'm running BIND 9.16.3-Ubuntu (ISC PPA) on a primary DNS server with a split view setup of an internal and an external view. All zones are signed with inline signing and auto-dnssec maintain. Some weeks ago I did my first ever ZSK and KSK rollover for every zone which was - in my view - carefully planned and executed and went well. After the old keys were unpublished I have deleted them. Now I noticed that bind was complaining about missing keys for a internal zone:

```
02-Jun-2020 20:00:35.893 general: warning: dns_dnssec_keylistfromrdataset: error reading /etc/bind/keys/Ksomefqdn.com.+008+62538.private: file not found
02-Jun-2020 20:00:35.893 general: warning: dns_dnssec_keylistfromrdataset: error reading /etc/bind/keys/Ksomefqdn.com.+008+21337.private: file not found
02-Jun-2020 20:00:35.893 general: warning: dns_dnssec_findzonekeys2: error reading /etc/bind/keys/Ksomefqdn.com.+008+62538.private: file not found
02-Jun-2020 20:00:35.893 general: warning: dns_dnssec_findzonekeys2: error reading /etc/bind/keys/Ksomefqdn.com.+008+21337.private: file not found
```

This happens at every `key event` (hourly) when bind says it is `reconfiguring zone keys`. When restarting bind I saw that it apparently loads an outdated zone serial for the signed zone. I then bumped the serial in the unsigned zone file, removed all `jbk`, `jnl`, `signed` and `signed.jnl` files for the zone, flushed the cache with `rndc flush` (probably unnecessary because I restarted later) and restarted bind.

The problem of the outdated serial is still there:

```
13-Jun-2020 18:39:31.364 zoneload: info: zone somefqdn.com/IN/internal-view (unsigned): loaded serial 2020061301
13-Jun-2020 18:39:31.364 zoneload: info: zone somefqdn.com/IN/internal-view (signed): loaded serial 2020052919 (DNSSEC signed)
```

Afterwards bind complains about the missing keys. I did not find other error messages.
Is there some other cache I have to empty, a database to flush or another file I have to delete?

Comment: Double check that bind loads zonefile exactly where you think it does. Also you may want not just to delete the files (in fact I am pretty sure that this can lead to problems) but properly use `rndc freeze` and `rndc thaw`.